# Find solutions of $\alpha$ so that equation has exactly one and exactly two complex roots respectively.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

> Consider equation for $\lambda\neq 0$, $$x^5+5\lambda x^4-x^3+(\alpha\lambda-4)x^2-(8\lambda+3)x+\lambda\alpha-2=0.$$ If $p, q$ are values of $\alpha$ for which equation has exactly one root $\in$ $\mathbf C$ independent of $\lambda$ and exactly two  roots $\in$ $\mathbf C$ independent of $\lambda$  then find $p, q$.

Where $\mathbf C$ denotes set of complex numbers.

I don't understand how can a polynomial have exactly one complex root,  I think that complex roots of any odd degree polynomial are always found in conjugate pairs.

Comment: Complex roots must come in conjugate pairs when the coefficients are all real. The only condition on $\lambda$ that you’ve given is that it’s nonzero.

Comment: Note, a real root independent of $\lambda$ also is $\in \mathbb C$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  write the equation as:

$$(x^5-x^3-4x^2-3x-2) + \lambda(5 x^4+\alpha x^2-8 x+\alpha)=0$$

Any root which is independent of $\,\lambda\,$ must be a common root of:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
x^5-x^3-4x^2-3x-2 &= 0\\
5 x^4+\alpha x^2-8 x+\alpha &= 0
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Note that the first of those factors nicely, and has one simple root and two double ones.